# Wifi Stopped scanning for Networks

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

[image: Wifi stopped scanning for nwtworks]

as you can see here my wifi card can't scan for networks, and it was working only 5 minutes ago I tried restarting network manager and tried connecting to my wifi network manually but that didnt do anything either, what should I do now?

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk|grep -iA3 net; lsusb; ifconfig`